# Relevant Field Survey123

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-survey123

I'm fairly new to using Survey123 and have ran into a problem. I've created a multiple choice question where you can select more than one answer. With each answer, I would like to show a specific relevant sub-question. Basically, if the answer is A, I want it to show only A sub question. If it's A and C, only show A and C sub questions. If it's C, only show C... So far, I have used the "${question1} = '1' or ${question1} = '2'" expression but that doesn't work.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Answered myself.. within the relevant field I have "selected(${MyField}, '1')". The "1" is the answer you would have under choices.